# Suppress autoplay on Google ytplayer

Tags: video, autoplay, ytplayer

I have a page with an embedded youtube video. The playerVar autoplay is set to 0. But when the page loads, the iframe delivered by the API is

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="autoplay;    encrypted-media" title="YouTube video player" width="533" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/myVideo?autoplay=0&amp;controls=1&amp;fs=0&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&amp;showInfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;widgetid=1"></iframe>
```

Note "allow="autoplay;  Why does this happen?? Furthermore, the video autoplays on some browsers/systems and not on others.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try to remove `autoplay;` from the `allow` attribute ;)

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="encrypted-media" title="YouTube video player" width="533" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/myVideo?autoplay=0&amp;controls=1&amp;fs=0&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&amp;showInfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;widgetid=1"></iframe
```

Comment: The allow attribute is automatically generated by the API, on the user's browser. Not present in code on page.